# ng-if only triggers once

Tags: angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

today i ran into a strange behaviour at an angular app.

We have an Array which we fill at the **component.ts** on nginit

```
for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    this.cluster[i] = [];
    for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
       this.cluster[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

in the **component.html** we use a for loop to iterate over the Array

```
<div *ngFor="let col of cluster; let iCol = index" class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-2 col-md-4 offset-md-0">
    <div *ngFor="let row of col; let iRow = index">
       <div*ngIf="(cluster.length < 2 && cluster[0].length < 4)">
            <p>Test</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If im not completly wrong we should get 3 prints of `"Test"` but we only get 1.

Can someone explain me where the error appears. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your second line the cluster array is only 1 dimensional empty array. And in your 4th line you make it 2 dimensional and fill it with false? What is the purpose of your array?

Comment: @ochs.tobi i create an Grid (for example 3x3) which can be filled with true. Kinda like noughts and crosses.

Comment: But the array you defined above is only 1x3 because the first for loop in only executed once.

Comment: @ochs.tobi for the moment true, but if will get filled with more rows while the app is running with user Interaction

Comment: @sHamann what happens when you remove the `*ngIf`. I can also see a missing double quote at the end, but I suppose that's just a typo in the question creation

Comment: @PierreDuc it will print out Test 3 times, and yes the Quote is just a typo. Sry for that one!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close double quotes.

> use this html code

```
<div *ngFor="let col of cluster; let iCol = index" class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-2 col-md-4 offset-md-0">
    <div *ngFor="let row of col; let iRow = index">
       <div *ngIf="(cluster.length < 2 && cluster[0].length < 4)">
            <p>Test</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly, just a Typo of me. Sry